# Passing input type file array

Tags: php, arrays, post, file-upload

I tried my best researching on how to pass an input type file array to another php page.
But I get stuck everytime I post the value from one page to the other.

I have this code written on the page cityaddinfo.php which on submits directs to the page cityadded.php

```
    <form method="POST" action="cityadded.php?city=<?php echo $city?>">

        <tr>
            <td>
            <?php
                $quecityimage=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `city_image` WHERE city_id=$city");
                echo "<b>city images</b><br>";

                while($cityimage=mysql_fetch_assoc($quecityimage))
                {
                    $pathcity=$cityimage['path'];
                    echo "<img src='$pathcity' width=\"400px\" height=\"200px\"/><br><br>";

                }
            ?>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
             <td>
            <p class="clone">  File:
            <input type="file" name="f_name[]" size="10" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 22px;"/>
            <p>
            <a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a>
            </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">  
            </td>
        </tr>
```

cityadded.php code:

```
    <?php
     echo $_GET['city'];
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   $a= $_POST['f_name'];
     foreach($a as $img)
     {
       echo $img;
     }
   }
   ?>
```

The code echo's the name of only one input type file name. Even if I add more than one files.
Can anybody help me out on how to post this input file array on other page?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have enctype = "multipart/form-data" set in your form tag.
You can access the file on your PHP script using $_FILES and not $_POST.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="file_sent" size="10" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 22px;"/>
```

**on PHP Page you can access the same using the following**

```
 $_FILES["file_sent"]["name"] - the name of the uploaded file
    $_FILES["file_sent"]["type"] - the type of the uploaded file
    $_FILES["file_sent"]["size"] - the size in kilobytes of the uploaded file
    $_FILES["file_sent"]["tmp_name"] - the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server
    $_FILES["file_sent"]["error"] - the error code resulting from the file upload
```

EDIT:
I dont see why you would want to have the other attributes on the file field in the HTML page. I dont think these attributes would work on a file field. Even  if the they do, move them to a stylesheet.

Refer to this.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php
you need to access them using indexes since you are passing an array of file elements.

Comment: Rahul: the input type file is sent to other page on 'submit', I tried using enctype and also accessing the file using $_FILES. Name of my input type file is 'f_name'. On accessing the file using $_FILES i get an error of 'Undefined Index: f_name'

Comment: do you still have square brackets in your field name - f_name[]??
Remove them. <input type="file" name="f_name" /> would do

Comment: @RahulNanwani Do you see the `add more` in the code that clones the `file` input?  Using the brackets turns it in to an array so that is possible.

Comment: Yes I am still using brackets in f_name[], Because I just dont have one input file to send. I would have some few files from 5-10 with same input file name to send. thats why I have kept the title of the question 'Passing input type file array'

Comment: ok then, I didn't know that. But then shouldn't it be accessed using an index then on the server side. like f_name[0], f_name[1]?

Comment: @rahulNanwani:  In order to access the file, first i need to Get the file on the other page.

Comment: I am making using of file attributes in php page on which the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of errors,

1. `$a= $_POST['f_name'];` you can not access file field like this you should use `$_FILES` instead.
2. When you want to upload file using form you should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form attribute I don't see that too. I think you need to learn some basics.

Comment: I corrected my errors, and actually they were not errors. but instead I removed it purposely to check diff methods. Since using $_FILES instead of $_POST gives me an error of 'Undefined Index: f_name'

Comment: @IshqMehta you would get that error if `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"` is not part of the initial `<form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_FILES instead of $_POST for files.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form :

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="cityadded.php?city=<?php echo $city?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```